# React Container not Re-Rending after Redux State Change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am working on Redux and React and I have run into an issue. I am making a book list, and once you click the book list you will see details about the book.

When I select a book, the action is correctly being handled and the state is changed.

```
// reducer_active_book.js
export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "BOOK_SELECTED":
            console.log("Current State [Reducer]: ",state);
            console.log("New State [Reducer]: ",action.payload);
            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;   
}
```

When I click a book, I get this in the console (so I know the above is functioning correctly)

[image]

Also I know from the above log that my container is aware, as mapStateToProps is being called.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class BookDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        if(!this.props.book) {
            return <div>Select a Book.</div>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Details For:</h3>
                <div>{this.props.book.title}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps called (connect)");
    return {book: state.activeBook};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookDetail);
```

Combine reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from "./reducer_books";
import ActiveBook from  "./reducer_active_book";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer,
  ActiveBook: ActiveBook
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The item never re-renders after the initial "Select a Book". What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your state has a `ActiveBook` not `activeBook` property:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps called (connect)");
    return {book: state.ActiveBook};
}
```

Comment: this is embarrassing, there goes my afternoon